# Xcode 7.1 PrototypeTools Linker Error (on simulator only)

Tags: ios, build, frameworks, linker, build-error

I'm trying to run my app in the iOS simulator using Xcode 7.1, but I'm getting a linker error. This is the error:

```
ld: file not found: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrototypeTools.framework/PrototypeTools for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems that this is a new issue, as I did not have it before upgrading to the new Xcode (which supported development for the newly released iOS 9.1). I have searched on Google but there are pretty much no relevant threads for this issue. Interestingly, the app works fine on a device.

I have tried resetting the simulator and cleaning/building again, but neither have worked. Has anyone else experienced this issue, and can you offer any advice?

Comment: r u using pods ? Error says that framework is misssing. Try to delete it and add the framework again

Comment: Hi @Mr.T, I am using Pods. But I am not using any framework called "PrototypeTools." What exactly am I supposed to delete/add again? Should I just reinstall all my pods? Thanks!

Comment: try removing the pod or updating the pod!!!

Comment: Hi, I removed and updated all pods, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is this giving error on previous version of iOS simulator as well i.e 8.4 ?

Comment: @Ali Yes, this happens for both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you don't need `PrototypeTools.framework`,you can delete it as the following steps:

`TARGETS -> "Your Project" -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`

Find the `PrototypeTools.framework`,and delete it.

If you're not sure you need `PrototypeTools.framework` or not.

1.`PrototypeTools.framework` is probably the 3rd static library,go to search and check the newest library,download it and replace with new one,and try it again.
2.If you don't need to do something on the Simulator,you don't need to care about it,just ignore it.

`.framework` is one kind of static library,if the developers of the `.framework` don't care much about the `Architecture` when building the static library.Some kinds of `Architecture` will not be supported.

x86_64 `Architecture` is for simulator only.Usually the static library `.framework` doesn't need to support this,because we test our app and run our app on the real device,this will increase the size of `.framework` static library,but some static libraries support most of the `Architecture`,both the simulator and the real device.

Comment: Hi, the interesting thing is that I don't even have PrototypeTools added as a framework. It is not listed under "Link Binary With Libraries."

Comment: If this situation,you can go to the folder to check whether you have this.

Comment: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrototypeTools.framework/PrototypeTools

Comment: There is no PrototypeTools framework in the PrivateFrameworks folder.